# Problema con variable

Tags: python, base-de-datos, gps

estoy haciendo un trabajo con GPS que me da coordenadas de latitud y longitud. He estado usando un codigo que trabaja con ubicaciones de una base de datos para determinar cual de ellos es más cercano a mi ubicación actual pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Paradero' referenced before assignment
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente, como verán tiene de entradas las variables de latitud y longitud
La función Hallardistancia obtiene la distancia entre dos puntos a partir de sus coordenadas y posteriormente busco en la lista una ubicación con menor distancia

```
def HallarParadaCerca(latB,lonB):
    dist=1000000
    print("Ubicacion actual: ("+str(latB)+";"+str(lonB)+")")
    for r in range(1,161):
        c.execute("SELECT * from Paraderos where ID="+ str(r))#selecciona la latitud del paradero
        ruta=c.fetchall()
        nombre=ruta[0][1]
        latP=ruta[0][2]
        lonP=ruta[0][3]
        d=HallarDistancia(latB, lonB, latP, lonP)
        if d<dist:
            dist=d
            Paradero=nombre
            lat=latP
            lon=lonP
            print(Paradero)

    print("Paradero mas cerca es: " + Paradero + " (lat :" + str(lat) + ";lon: " + str(lon) + ")")
    print("A un distancia de: "+str(dist)+" m")
    return Paradero
```

Comment: Al parecer el problema es porque si en todas las iteraciones del for, `d >= dist`, entonces la rutina nunca va a entrar en el `if` y luego más abajo en `print("Paradero mas cerca es: " + paradero + ...)` estás invocando a la variable `Paradero` que no estará asignada. Aún así sería extraño ya que `dist` inicial es un valor bastante grande, a menos que estés usando escalas muy pequeñas (centímetros por ejemplo). Podrías probar agregando un par de ceros más a la variable `dist` a ver si ya no da el error.

Answer (score 0):

La asignación a la variable `Paradero` se produce dentro de un bucle for y a su vez dentro de un bloque if. Si no consigues pasar la condición `d<dist`, un poco más abajo el `print()` te sacará ese error porque la variable Paradero nunca habrá sido definida, dado que tampoco la has iniciado con un valor predeterminado.  Utiliza un valor inicial, fuera del bucle for, que te sirva para prevenir ese caso.

Como añadido, mencionaré que no deberías concatenar jamás cadenas que recibas para formar sentencias SQL, sino en su lugar usar consultas preparadas o alguna biblioteca para BB.DD. que lo haga sola.